# How to update only affected columns on db2 while using join

Tags: sql, database, join, db2, sql-update

I want to make an update in a table but only for the values affected, so I have to use `where exists` but apparently it won't work when using a join operation. Does anyone know why this happen and how to do it?

```
update semester_workload tA
set tA.account = (SELECT DISTINCT (t2.WORKING - t2.WORKLOAD) FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1
        join SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2 on t1.ID_LECTURER = t2.ID_LECTURER
        WHERE t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS10' AND tA.ID_SW = t2.ID_SW);
where exists (SELECT 1 FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1        
        join SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2 on t1.ID_LECTURER = t2.ID_LECTURER
        WHERE t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS10' AND tA.ID_SW = t2.ID_SW);
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result will explain your problem better

Comment: You have an extra `;` before the where -- are there other problems?